# MS Access: Upload multiple files from one button

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to upload multiple files at once into an access database via the use of a button. However only one file will upload at a time.

When the button is clicked it calls a sub procedure. My code is below:

`Private Sub btnImport_Click()
'Calls the procdure that imports raw files
Call Module1.ImportRawFiles 
End Sub`

```
Public Sub ImportRawFiles()
Dim oFileDiag As Office.FileDialog
Dim path As String: path = ""
Dim oFSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim FileSelected As Variant

Set oFileDiag = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker) ''Picks file to import
oFileDiag.AllowMultiSelect = True ''Allows multiple files to be selected
oFileDiag.Title = "Please select the reports to upload"
oFileDiag.Filters.Clear
oFileDiag.Filters.Add "Excel Spreadsheets", "*.xlsx, *.xls" ''Only allows xlsx and xls file types to upload

If oFileDiag.Show Then
    For Each FileSelected In oFileDiag.SelectedItems
           Form_Homepage.txtFileName = FileSelected
    Next
End If

If Nz(Form_Homepage.txtFileName, "") = "" Then
    MsgBox "No files selected please select a file"
    Exit Sub
End If

If oFileDiag.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then path = oFileDiag.SelectedItems(1)
    If Len(path) > 0 Then
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, oFSO.GetFileName(Form_Homepage.txtFileName), path, 1

    MsgBox "The " & oFSO.GetFileName(Form_Homepage.txtFileName) & " file has been uploaded"
Else
    MsgBox "File not found"
End If
```

Does anyone know why only one file is uploading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping through all selected files to assign `Form_Homepage.txtFileName` but then not doing anything else in that same loop:

```
If oFileDiag.Show Then
    For Each FileSelected In oFileDiag.SelectedItems
           Form_Homepage.txtFileName = FileSelected
    Next
End If
```

So by end of the loop, the last selected file is assigned, ignoring all the others, then your later logic statements only perform on that one file.

One solution would be to move your action logic up to the same loop.  So move your IF statements into the assignment loop, that way they operate on each iterative assignment of your variable.

Comment: Thank you so much, such a simple fix.